# Akka Http Code vrs Spring Boot Application

Tags: spring-boot, akka-http

I am new to Akka HTTP, i recently moved from Spring Boot Application to Akka HTTP seeing Actor model benefits but i am facing one issue.

max-connection property in spring boot which allows to set max connection property for spring boot application, i am not able to set it in my new akka http application.

FYI: I developed new application using akkaHTTP but performance comparison reports for akkaHTTP is very less from SpringBoot application in terms of max connection and response time. For testing i used Jmeter to put load in both application but for 2000 user per second akkaHTTP code is very bad and spring boot is awesome. So during analysis is figured out one property as max-conection which i have configured in spring-boot is enhancing it's performance.

How to set this in akkaHTTP? Can any one help me for this work around.

**NOTE**: i have seen this configuration for akkahttp code *http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/10.0.9/scala/http/configuration.html*
but not able to figure out how to use it.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

**File Based Configuration**

As indicated in the link you provided:

> Usually this means that you provide an application.conf which contains
>   all the application-specific settings that differ from the default
>   ones provided by the reference configuration files from the individual
>   Akka modules.

In my sbt based projects the directory structure looks like:

```
/projectDir
           /build.sbt
           /resources
                     /application.conf
           /src
               /main
                    /scala
```

In the `/projectDir/resources/application.conf` you can add the configuration:

```
akka.http {
  max-connections = 42
}
```

This will [automatically get picked up](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/general/configuration.html#where-configuration-is-read-from) by the `ActorSystem`:

> This means roughly that the default is to parse all application.conf,
>   application.json and application.properties found at the root of the
>   class path—please refer to the aforementioned documentation for
>   details.

**Code Based Configuration**

You can specify the parameter in code as well:

```
val config : Config = 
  ConfigFactory parseString """akka.http.max-connections = 42"""
```

And then use this config to create the ActorSystem:

```
implicit val actorSystem = ActorSystem("actorSystemName", config)
implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()

val bindingFuture = Http().bindAndHandle(...)
```